# how to change the Geometry of Polyline in QGIS using Python

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

[image: Before Change Geometry]

I have two layers with multiple features, BlackLayer and YellowLayer. As i mentioned in the above image there are one yellow feature on two black features.I would like to change the geometry of yellow feature to black feature as i shown in below image.

[image: after change geometry]

what i tried is:

```
lineLayer = iface.activeLayer()
provider = lineLayer.dataProvider()

spIndex = QgsSpatialIndex() #create spatial index object

feat = QgsFeature()
fit = provider.getFeatures() #gets all features in layer

#insert features to index
while fit.nextFeature(feat):
    spIndex.insertFeature(feat)

pt = QgsPoint(-0.00062201,0.00001746)

#QgsSpatialIndex.nearestNeighbor (QgsPoint point, int neighbors)
nearestIds = spIndex.nearestNeighbor(pt,1) # we need only one neighbour

featureId = nearestIds[0]
fit2 = lineLayer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFid(featureId))
ftr = QgsFeature()
fit2.nextFeature(ftr)         
vertices = ftr.geometry().asPolyline() 
polyline = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(vertices )
provider.changeGeometryValues({ftr.id(): polyline})
```

Please help me with this ..!!!